# Whats the difference between schema and model?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am just starting ate Phoenix, and i didnt understand very well one thing, i searched and saw there schemas are the database structure and models have a high level and handles with the logic, but in phoenix we only have schemas, so for example if i would do a password hash, it should be in the user schema? Or should i put it in a controller?

Comment: Hashes are usually done in `changeset` callback that indeed belongs to schemas. I am not sure what you refer to as “model.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want your MVC apps to have "thin controllers" -- that's a recommendation that holds across multiple languages.  In some languages/frameworks, that's critical because testing controllers can be quite difficult.  Although testing controllers is relatively simple in a functional language like Elixir and a well-structured framework like Phoenix, you should still keep your controllers as lean as possible. To put it simply, controllers should connect a service module (often called a "context" in Phoenix) with a view.  Usually there's not a whole lot of logic in them at all.

"Schemas" can be a confusing term -- take a moment to appreciate that different databases use different terminology to refer to (more or less) the same components. E.g. a "database" in MySQL is called a "schema" in Oracle or Postgres.  In Ecto, the "schema" is analogous to an ORM "model" in many other frameworks: an Ecto schema represents in code the "shape" of a specific database table (so maybe that's why they use the same term).

However, in your case, something like a calculated field of a password hash should be in the same module as the Ecto schema.  (Yes, Ecto does some macro magic when it defines the shape of the table in code, but it's still a module and it is the recommended place to put `changeset` functions that deal with validating and mutating data before it goes into the database).

If you ever find yourself wondering where some functionality should go, ask yourself where you would put the code if the user input was coming from the CLI instead from the web.  If you had a CLI mix task that created a user with a password, would you use the web controller?  No, you wouldn't: the controller is just the go-between that connects the web request/response with the underlying model/schema.  You wouldn't want to duplicate the code that calculated the password hash just because you wanted to create it for a CLI script, so that leaves you with the logical place to put it: in the schema.

The Ecto changesets allow you to modify data on the way in to the database.  You might hear this referred to as a "mutation" in some frameworks, or a "calculated field."

Here's an example that calculates a "created_at" field (yes, you could do this in the database, but it's a useful example of how to do a calculated field in code):

```
  @doc false
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:username,:email])
    |> validate_required([:username,:email])
    |> add_created_at()
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
    |> unique_constraint(:email)
  end

  defp add_created_at(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{
        valid?: true,
        changes: _user
      } ->
        put_change(
          changeset,
          :created_at,
          DateTime.utc_now
          |> DateTime.truncate(:second)
        )
      _ ->
        changeset
    end
  end
```

And here's an example of calculating a password hash to be stored in your database -- using the `Argon2` package. This also adds a field that identifies which algorithm was used to hash the password (as a string, useful for reference):

```
  def changeset(user, attrs) do
    user
    |> cast(attrs, [:username, :password])
    |> validate_required([:username, :password])
    |> validate_length(:password, min: 8, max: 100)
    |> unique_constraint(:username)
    |> put_password_hash()
  end


  defp put_password_hash(changeset) do
    case changeset do
      %Ecto.Changeset{
        valid?: true,
        changes: %{
          password: plain_text
        }
      } ->
        put_change(changeset, :password_hash, Argon2.hash_pwd_salt(plain_text))
        |> put_change(:algorithm, "argon2")

      _ ->
        changeset
    end
  end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it was clear, i am just newbie at phoenix, studied elixir along 2 weeks and now im pratice elixir doing a trello clone

my code is really close from that, im using tdd so its been really good to learn thinks like phoenix structure, you can follow my progress [here](https://github.com/uduDudu/TrelloClone)